# Get only single field data using flask session query

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For example, I have a database table named `User` that has the following fields: `id` , `name`, and `age`. I want to only get data of the field `age`. Currently, I am getting data of all the fields in a query. How can I get data of just one field?

```
session.query(User)
        .filter_by(
            id=1
        )
        .all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mention the column name you want in the query:

```
rows = session.query(User.age).filter_by(id=1).all()
```

Actually SqlAlchemy queries for attributes return KeyedTuples which behave like a named tuple.

that's why your data look like that, you can access them by index or name :

```
rows = [i[0] for i in rows]
#or 
rows = [i.age for i in rows]

rows
```

read more about [KeyedTuple](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple)  here.

Comment: thanks for reply sir . I am getting output in something form like this `[(20,),(21,),]`. sir I didn't get what form is this. can't I get this in simple form like `[20,21]` ?

Comment: how does data look like in age column in original table?

Comment: Sir just int type ,  like  20 and 21

Comment: actually I just want to iterate  over this data

Comment: @newbir see updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two statements to reduce the columns to your requirements.

[load_only](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only):

```
User.query.options(load_only('age')).all()
```

[with_entities](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities):

```
User.query.with_entities(User.age).all()
```

Comment: I am using `sessions` actually